# LiteDb compatibility between different languages

Tags: python, c#, litedb

I have a .Net app that saves this class in LiteDb:

```
public class GSR_raw
    {
        public string SystemStamp { get; set; }

        public float unknow { get; set; }

        public float s { get; set; }

        public float UnixTimeStamp { get; set; }

        public float InternalSignal { get; set; }

        public float Conductance { get; set; }

        public float uS { get; set; }

    }
```

This, of course, generates a .DB file that i'm unable to read using python.

This is the definition of the class in python:

```
class GSR_raw:

    def __init__(self, SystemStamp: str, unknow: float, s: float,UnixTimeStamp: float, InternalSignal: float, Conductance: float, uS: float):
        self.SystemStamp = SystemStamp
        self.unknow = unknow
        self.s = s
        self.UnixTimeStamp = UnixTimeStamp
        self.InternalSignal = InternalSignal
        self.Conductance = Conductance
        self.uS = uS

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.__dict__)
```

The error message says: **"No table of <class 'classes.GSR_raw'> exists in this database"**

The python code that tries to read:

```
def get_raw_data(path):

    disk_db = DiskDatabase(path)
    temp_data = list(disk_db.select(GSR_raw))
```

The path is correct as I have already test it.

Is this a problem of compatibility of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that you've posted I assume that for python you are using this [litedb](https://github.com/JonathanVusich/litedb) package,
and for C# this [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/litedb).

Those are two different databases, it is no wonder that you can't get your object with python db client.

If you want to work with same objects in different languages, I think, it is better to use some kind of a contract and language agnostic serialization, you can take a look at [apache thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/), [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) or if those seems to be an overkill - simple json serialization.